Lifting a morphism between quasi-projective varieties
Let $\mathcal{V}$ be an affine algebraic variety over $\mathbb{R}$, $G$ be a finite group acting freely on $\mathcal{V}$.  Consider the quotient space $Y:=\mathcal{V}/G$, which itself is a quasi-algebraic variety.
Updated:
Let $\mathbb{A}^n$ be the $n$-dimensional affine space over $\mathbb{R}$ and consider a regular map
$f:\mathbb{A}^n\to \mathcal{V}/G$.
When can we guarantee that there is a lift $F:\mathbb{A}^n\to \mathcal{V}$ of $f$; i.e.
$$
\pi\circ F = f
$$
where $\pi:\mathcal{V}\to \mathcal{V}/G$ is the natural quotient map?

Related: Lifting polynomial functions

No: take $\mathcal{W}=\mathcal{V}/G$ and $f=\operatorname{Id} $.

What about the case where $\mathcal{W}$ is the affine space?  (I updated the question to only consider this strong assumption case).

Mega-cool; thanks @LSpice

Affine space is algebraically simply connected (in characteristic zero).  So the finite, etale cover $\mathbb{A}^n\times_{f,Y,q} \mathcal{V}$ of $\mathbb{A}^n$ admits a section.  The composition of this section with the second projection is a lift $F$.  This completely fails in positive characteristic (consider Artin-Schreier covers).

@JasonStarr Do you have a reference for the existence of this section?  I'm looking at the stacks project but cannot finte one.

Also @JasonStarr , if $f$ is invariant with respect to some other group action, must its lift also be?

You should read about the concept of an etale local system. I believe what Jason Starr is saying is that the fibred product forms an etale local system over affine n-space. Etale local systems are equivalent to representations of the fundamental group, and their global sections are isomorphic to the invariants of the representation. Since the representation is of the trivial group, all sections extend globally. Another important keyword in this context is "monodromy".

The standard reference is SGA 1.  It is a bit tricky to find the "correct" reference.  Late in SGA 1, after proving the comparison theorem, Grothendieck deduces that the etale fundamental groups of proper, smooth curves equal the profinite completions of the usual finitely presented groups (whose unique relation is a product of commutators).  However, there are much simpler proofs that the projective line has trivial etale fundamental group (and probably there is a reference somewhere earlier in SGA 1).
